# How to get a unique id from every browser with php?

Tags: php

I've a website and I want to track every user who visits my website.I thought  using the IP address as unique id. The plan was  very simple to get IP address sign-up to the database and store information. Then if user visits again a track system uses his IP Address to track his previous information and inserting new information, but unfortunately the IP Address is changing from time to time. How can I get unique something or static IP Address?

Comment: Easy, add a facebook widget :-)

Comment: IPs are not unique to users, not just over time, but *ever*. Set a tracking cookie.

Comment: Try to research session management, cookies, browser fingerprinting

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `browscap` library and then make an `md5` of the browser information:

```
$bc = new \phpbrowscap\Browscap('data/');
$current_browser = $bc->getBrowser(null,true);
$str = json_encode($current_browser);
$browser_id = md5($str);
```

Comment: How do I install browscap.ini in the hosting server?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/browscap/issues/2344999 see this

Comment: I've downloaded browscap library from github and uploaded it on my server but I don't know which file to include or require in order the library to work

Comment: I don't use composer as I'm using hosting server

Answer (score 0):

Just use cookies so user can decide if they want to get tracked on your site.

```
//generate unique id
$uniqid = bin2hex (openssl_random_pseudo_bytes (64));

//set cookie
setcookie ("cookie_name", $uniqid);

//--> now store uniqid in your database to identify the user.

//receive the cookie by next visit
$uniqid = $_COOKIE["cookie_name"]
```

Comment: Despite its name, `uniqid` is hardly globally unique and would be unsuitable for generating ids to track potentially millions of users over a long time.

Comment: @deceze you are right. i just wanted to show the cookie-part. I updated my answer to make the id more unique.

Comment: Still not much better. `md5` doesn't increase entropy, if anything it reduces it. You should use `random_bytes` or read from `/dev/urandom` or use UUIDs.